# R terra overlap vectors and return land areas

Tags: r, vector, overlap, terra

I am following the example for terra::intersect

```
library(terra)
f <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")
v <- vect(f)
e <- ext(5.6, 6, 49.55, 49.7)
x <- intersect(v, e)
p <- vect(c("POLYGON ((5.8 49.8, 6 49.9, 6.15 49.8, 6 49.6, 5.8 49.8))",
            "POLYGON ((6.3 49.9, 6.2 49.7, 6.3 49.6, 6.5 49.8, 6.3 49.9))"), crs=crs(v))
values(p) <- data.frame(pid=1:2, area=expanse(p))
y <- intersect(v, p)
```

and what I ultimately want it so summarise the land area of all the polygons created by joining p and v. What I mean is, for each polygon in p, how many ha of polygon is in Diekirch, Grevenmacher, and Luxembourg.

I try this:

```
lapply(y, FUN=expanse, unit="ha")
expanse(v)

yy <- union(v,p)
lapply(yy, FUN=expanse, unit="ha")
```

but in both cases, expanse returns the same values as

```
expanse(v)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
e <- expanse(y, unit="km")
aggregate(cbind(area=e), y[,c("pid", "NAME_1"), drop=TRUE], sum)

#  pid       NAME_1       area
#1   1     Diekirch 226.271445
#2   2     Diekirch   8.147181
#3   2 Grevenmacher 286.019968
#4   1   Luxembourg 194.340843
#5   2   Luxembourg  32.281530
```

Or like this (I would prefer the approach above because it avoids the need to aggregate polygons)

```
z <- aggregate(y, c("pid", "NAME_1"))
cbind(z[, c("pid", "NAME_1"), drop=TRUE], 
                 area=expanse(z, unit="km"))

#  pid       NAME_1       area
#1   1     Diekirch 226.271445
#2   1   Luxembourg 194.340843
#3   2     Diekirch   8.147181
#4   2 Grevenmacher 286.019968
#5   2   Luxembourg  32.281530
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach with `sf` and `tidyverse`:

```
library(terra)
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

f <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")
v <- vect(f)
e <- ext(5.6, 6, 49.55, 49.7)
x <- intersect(v, e)
p <- vect(c("POLYGON ((5.8 49.8, 6 49.9, 6.15 49.8, 6 49.6, 5.8 49.8))",
            "POLYGON ((6.3 49.9, 6.2 49.7, 6.3 49.6, 6.5 49.8, 6.3 49.9))"), crs=crs(v))
values(p) <- data.frame(pid=1:2, area=expanse(p))
y <- terra::intersect(v, p)

# sanity check: view data, cropping polygons, and cropped layer
plot(v)
plot(p, add = TRUE, col = "red")
plot(y, add = TRUE, col = "blue")

# convert to sf (data frame), mutate an area, and sum area per name group
st_as_sf(y) %>% 
  mutate(area = st_area(geometry)) %>% 
  group_by(NAME_1) %>% 
  summarise(area_sum = sum(area)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

This returns the summed area per name group:

```
Simple feature collection with 3 features and 2 fields
Geometry type: GEOMETRY
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 5.8 ymin: 49.6 xmax: 6.5 ymax: 49.9
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  NAME_1         area_sum                             geometry
  <chr>             [m^2]                       <GEOMETRY [°]>
1 Diekirch     233635561. MULTIPOLYGON (((6.285424 49.87085, …
2 Grevenmacher 285068244. POLYGON ((6.42977 49.72977, 6.5 49.…
3 Luxembourg   225869770. MULTIPOLYGON (((6.217318 49.68268, …
```

Comment: I get `Error in UseMethod("st_as_sf") : 
  no applicable method for 'st_as_sf' applied to an object of class "list"` after `st_as_sf(y) ...`

Comment: This was a sneaky bug. The `intersect` argument is imported by dplyr and terra, so we need to explicitly call it from terra. See revised code above. Should work now.